# flash players in Windows Phones

Tags: internet-explorer, video, flash-player

I am running Windows Phone 7.5 OS in my mobile, and I am having problems trying to play videos in my internet explorer in the phone because there is no flash.

My first question is "Is there a way or any work around to play flash videos in the browser?"

And if not "Are we getting this feature in Windows Phone 8"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to play all online flash videos with Windows Phone. Flash will not be added to Windows Phone 8 as Adobe is [no longer developing](http://www.winrumors.com/no-flash-for-windows-phone-as-adobe-kills-off-mobile-development/) the mobile version.

A current (and partial) solution that works on some sites is [Metro Browser](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/metro-browser/60aa8848-6cc8-4ec4-94b7-1d134550b57b).

Comment: Let MS added Flash support for Windows RT

Answer (score 0):

You can install flash if you have an interop unlocked device I believe with homebrew security certificate other wise your better off downloading the cap file separately and deploying to unlocked device as older versions of flash are still supported just don't update them!

Comment: Are you sure that you are referring to Windows Phone and not Windows Mobile? This site only covers Windows Phone.